# How to compare with the previous line after reassignment

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Compare each row of column A with the previous row
If greater than, reassign to the value of the previous row
If less than, the value is unchanged
Now the problem is that each time the comparison is made with the original value
What I want is, to compare with the previous line after reassignment

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d={'A':[16,19,18,15,13,16]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['A_changed']=np.where(df.A>df.A.shift(),df.A.shift(),df.A)
df
```

```py
    A   A_changed
0   16  16.0
1   19  16.0
2   18  18.0
3   15  15.0
4   13  13.0
5   16  13.0
```

expected output

```
 A   A_changed
0   16  16.0
1   19  16.0
2   18  16.0
3   15  15.0
4   13  13.0
5   16  13.0
```

Comment: Please give some explanation as to what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I've reformulated the question

Comment: Show us your expected output please.

Comment: expected output have done

Comment: You want the `cummin` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to do [`cummin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cummin.html#pandas-dataframe-cummin)?

```
df['compare_min'] = df['A'].cummin()
```

Output:

```
    A  compare  compare_min
0   5      5.0            5
1  14      5.0            5
2  12     12.0            5
3  15     12.0            5
4  13     13.0            5
5  16     13.0            5
```

---

```
df['b'] = [10, 11, 12, 5, 8, 2]

df['compare_min_b'] = df['b'].cummin()
```

Output:

```
    A  compare  compare_min   b  compare_min_b
0   5      5.0            5  10             10
1  14      5.0            5  11             10
2  12     12.0            5  12             10
3  15     12.0            5   5              5
4  13     13.0            5   8              5
5  16     13.0            5   2              2
```

**Update** using your example, this exactly what cummin does:

```
d={'A':[16,19,18,15,13,16]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['A_change'] = df['A'].cummin()
df
```

Output:

```
    A  A_changed  A_change
0  16       16.0        16
1  19       16.0        16
2  18       18.0        16
3  15       15.0        15
4  13       13.0        13
5  16       13.0        13
```

Here is why your code will not work:

```
d={'A':[16,19,18,15,13,16]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df['A_shift'] = df['A'].shift()
df
```

Output:

```
    A  A_shift
0  16      NaN
1  19     16.0
2  18     19.0
3  15     18.0
4  13     15.0
5  16     13.0
```

Look at the output of the shifted column, what you want to do is keep the cumulative mine instead of just comparing A to shifted A. Hence index 2 is not giving you what you expected.

Comment: I don't want to get the min， I need a method to solve the problem.

Comment: @junyu Can you give me a english explanation of what the problem is? It is not clear what the problem is or your desired result.

Comment: How to compare with the previous line after reassignment

Comment: This is exactly what cummin is doing!

Comment: This is why cummin function was written to handle this situtation.